# Missing package to enable rendering OpenAI Gym in Colab

Tags: rendering, google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I'm attempting to render OpenAI Gym environments in Colab via a Mac using the StarAI code referenced in previous questions on this topic. However, it fails. The key error (at least the first error) is shown in full below, but the import part seems to be "Please install xdpyinfo!"

PyPI doesn't have xdpyinfo. What is it and how do I install it?

Full error message:

482780428160 abstractdisplay.py:151] xdpyinfo was not found, X start can not be checked! Please install xdpyinfo!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've seen the same error, and solved it by installing [x11-utils package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/x11-utils) which includes xdpyinfo command.

```
!apt-get install x11-utils
```